# appengine channel api only broadcasts "disconnected" messages.

Tags: python, google-app-engine, push, channel

Using GAE/python and the channel api. I also enabled the "channel presence" inbound service to react on users opening/closing channels.

This setup has been working for the last month flawlessly.

Starting from yesterday I'm getting a weird problem in which I only get /_ah/disconnected posts without the matching /_ah/connected posts.

From the client (js) point of view it seems like the channel is open and everything is fine.

Comment: P.S. it works fine on the devserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies; this was an issue in production and was fixed early this morning:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7236